# Why this error? Gtk.TextView.scroll_to_iter() takes exactly 6 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, function, gtk3

Disclaimer, I'm obviously a bit of a newb.

I am sending data to a function with 2 pieces of data yet I am getting the error :

```
Gtk.TextView.scroll_to_iter() takes exactly 6 arguments (3 given)
```

I've played around a bit with different things but asking here.

This is my button, that calls the function:

```
def on_button_create_uuid_clicked(self, widget):
    self.log_output("New Code Generated. Press the 'Copy Code' button. \n", self.log_output)  # output to log
```

This is the function:

```
def log_output(self, textToWrite, widget):
    textIter = self.logBuffer.get_end_iter()  # get_start_iter / get_end_iter for placing text at start or end of the buffer/textView
    self.logBuffer.insert(textIter, textToWrite)  # insert at the text iter point
    self.logView.scroll_to_iter(textIter, 0.1)  # scroll to the text iter  ((((((NOT WORKING!))))
```

So the error message is then:

```
TypeError: Gtk.TextView.scroll_to_iter() takes exactly 6 arguments (3 given)
```

This confuses me as I'm sending two arguments and my function is expecting 3 yet the error is showing wildly different numbers.

Now this HAS to be something to do with my lack of skill, but I'm all ears if someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.  Currently I just can't see what it is I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-scroll-to-iter)?

Comment: I am a GOOSE!  Thank you for that.  I thought it was my function.  I wasn't even reading the error properly.  Thanks again and sorry for the trouble